# Exclude Kubernetes namespaces from prometheus scraping

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I have deployed Prometheus using the community helm chart and would like to scrape the metrics from a specific namespace and drop the metrics from all the other namespaces. I have used the below scrape config, but it doesn't seem to work. Also tried using Drop action.

```
    - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: node
      relabel_configs:
        - action: keep
          source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
          target_label: accounts
```

Comment: You need to use `regex: accounts` instead of `target_label: accounts` for `keep` action to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Monitor only one namespace metrics - Prometheus with Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070150/monitor-only-one-namespace-metrics-prometheus-with-kubernetes)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints
  namespaces:
    names:
    - my-namespace-to-monitor
```

Comment: tried with the above config, Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found something like this: https://www.robustperception.io/dropping-metrics-at-scrape-time-with-prometheus

So I would try changing the example from the post to something like this:

```yaml
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: node
    metric_relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [ __meta_kubernetes_namespace ]
        regex: 'accounts'
        action: drop
```