# kube-prometheus-stack / drop namespace

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator, kube-prometheus-stack

i m trying to drop a namespace, stop prometheus to scrape anything from it.
i have tried so many ways i got from the internet and the prometheus documentation. none seems to work.

i tried to set the 'prometheus.serviceMonitor.relabelings',

`- source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name, __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name, __meta_kubernetes_namespace, namespace] separator: ; regex: (vicken|postgres)`

and the generated config shows below, I still have data coming from that namespace. anyone knows how?

```
- job_name: serviceMonitor/ddhub-demo/my-kube-stack-kube-prometh-prometheus/0
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 30s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  follow_redirects: true
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [job]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: __tmp_prometheus_job_name
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_app]
    separator: ;
    regex: kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_release]
    separator: ;
    regex: my-kube-stack
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_self_monitor]
    separator: ;
    regex: "true"
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: web
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: Node;(.*)
    target_label: node
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: Pod;(.*)
    target_label: pod
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: namespace
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: service
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: pod
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: container
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: job
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: endpoint
    replacement: web
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name, __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name,
      __meta_kubernetes_namespace, namespace]
    separator: ;
    regex: (vicken|postgres)
    replacement: $1
    action: drop
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    modulus: 1
    target_label: __tmp_hash
    replacement: $1
    action: hashmod
  - source_labels: [__tmp_hash]
    separator: ;
    regex: "0"
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints
    kubeconfig_file: ""
    follow_redirects: true
    namespaces:
      names:
      - kube-demo`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Prometheus Operator, you cannot manually interfere with the prometheus config file. The Operator will overwrite your changes.

You will have success with using the `serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector` in your `Prometheus` definition. This will allow you to explicitly define the namespaces from which you want to pick up `serviceMonitor` objects. However, it is possible to have a cross reference, so if you additionally also explicitly specify targets appropriately in your `serviceMonitor` using the `namespaceSelector` you can make sure to only specify what you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

For namespaces, what I've found if you're using the prometheus operator or the later `kube-prometheus-stack` chart is you need to relabel the namespace AND apply a metric relabel for the namespace you want to keep, e.g.:

```
kube-state-metrics:
  prometheus:
    monitor:
      metricRelabelings:
      - sourceLabels: [ namespace ]
        regex: my_namespace
        action: keep
      relabelings:
       - sourceLabels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
         separator: ;
         regex: ^(.*)$
         targetLabel: namespace
         replacement: $1
         action: replace
```

Of course replace `my_namespace` with your target namespace. I've tried this with `keep` but I suspect it will work with `drop` as well.