# How can monitoring be limited to single namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, prometheus, grafana

I have used the prometheus deployment from the link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.16/samples/addons/prometheus.yaml.

We want prometheus to monitor a single namespace which shall help us use prometheus and grafana in single namespace as we do not get to have users separation based on namespaces in a single deployment for the complete cluster. I did follow the suggestion in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070150) but no complete configmap YAML was provided there.

However with a basic idea I have updated the configmap as below:

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: v1
data:
  alerting_rules.yml: |
    {}
  alerts: |
    {}
  prometheus.yml: |
    global:
      evaluation_interval: 1m
      scrape_interval: 15s
      scrape_timeout: 10s
    rule_files:
    - /etc/config/recording_rules.yml
    - /etc/config/alerting_rules.yml
    - /etc/config/rules
    - /etc/config/alerts
    scrape_configs:
    - job_name: prometheus
      static_configs:
      - targets:
        - localhost:9090
    - bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
      job_name: kubernetes-apiservers
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: default;kubernetes;https
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_name
        - __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name
      scheme: https
      tls_config:
        ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        insecure_skip_verify: true
    - bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
      job_name: kubernetes-nodes
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: node
      relabel_configs:
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
      - replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
        target_label: __address__
      - regex: (.+)
        replacement: /api/v1/nodes/$1/proxy/metrics
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_node_name
        target_label: __metrics_path__
      scheme: https
      tls_config:
        ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        insecure_skip_verify: true
    - bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
      job_name: kubernetes-nodes-cadvisor
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: node
      relabel_configs:
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
      - replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
        target_label: __address__
      - regex: (.+)
        replacement: /api/v1/nodes/$1/proxy/metrics/cadvisor
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_node_name
        target_label: __metrics_path__
      scheme: https
      tls_config:
        ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        insecure_skip_verify: true
    - honor_labels: true
      job_name: kubernetes-service-endpoints
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: true
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape
      - action: drop
        regex: true
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape_slow
      - action: replace
        regex: (https?)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme
        target_label: __scheme__
      - action: replace
        regex: (.+)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path
        target_label: __metrics_path__
      - action: replace
        regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
        replacement: $1:$2
        source_labels:
        - __address__
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port
        target_label: __address__
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_param_(.+)
        replacement: __param_$1
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        target_label: namespace
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_name
        target_label: service
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name
        target_label: node
    - honor_labels: true
      job_name: kubernetes-service-endpoints-slow
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: true
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape_slow
      - action: replace
        regex: (https?)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme
        target_label: __scheme__
      - action: replace
        regex: (.+)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path
        target_label: __metrics_path__
      - action: replace
        regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
        replacement: $1:$2
        source_labels:
        - __address__
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port
        target_label: __address__
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_param_(.+)
        replacement: __param_$1
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        target_label: namespace
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_name
        target_label: service
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name
        target_label: node
      scrape_interval: 5m
      scrape_timeout: 30s
    - honor_labels: true
      job_name: prometheus-pushgateway
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: service
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: pushgateway
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_probe
    - honor_labels: true
      job_name: kubernetes-services
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: service
      metrics_path: /probe
      params:
        module:
        - http_2xx
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: true
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_probe
      - source_labels:
        - __address__
        target_label: __param_target
      - replacement: blackbox
        target_label: __address__
      - source_labels:
        - __param_target
        target_label: instance
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
      - source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        target_label: namespace
      - source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_name
        target_label: service
    - honor_labels: true
      job_name: kubernetes-pods
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
        namespaces:
          names:
          - canary
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: true
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape
      - action: drop
        regex: true
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape_slow
      - action: replace
        regex: (https?)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme
        target_label: __scheme__
      - action: replace
        regex: (.+)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path
        target_label: __metrics_path__
      - action: replace
        regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
        replacement: $1:$2
        source_labels:
        - __address__
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port
        target_label: __address__
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_param_(.+)
        replacement: __param_$1
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        target_label: namespace
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_name
        target_label: pod
      - action: drop
        regex: Pending|Succeeded|Failed|Completed
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_phase
    - job_name: "kubernetes-cadvisor"
      scheme: https
      metrics_path: /metrics/cadvisor
      tls_config:
        ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        # disable certificate verification by uncommenting the line below.
        #
        # insecure_skip_verify: true
      authorization:
        credentials_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: node
      relabel_configs:
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
      metric_relabel_configs:
        - action: keep
          source_labels: [namespace]
          regex: canary
    - honor_labels: true
      job_name: kubernetes-pods-slow
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
        namespaces:
          names:
          - canary
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: true
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape_slow
      - action: replace
        regex: (https?)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme
        target_label: __scheme__
      - action: replace
        regex: (.+)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path
        target_label: __metrics_path__
      - action: replace
        regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
        replacement: $1:$2
        source_labels:
        - __address__
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port
        target_label: __address__
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_param_(.+)
        replacement: __param_$1
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        target_label: namespace
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_name
        target_label: pod
      - action: drop
        regex: Pending|Succeeded|Failed|Completed
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_phase
      scrape_interval: 5m
      scrape_timeout: 30s
  recording_rules.yml: |
    {}
  rules: |
    {}
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"alerting_rules.yml":"{}\n","alerts":"{}\n","prometheus.yml":"global:\n  evaluation_interval: 1m\n  scrape_interval: 15s\n  scrape_timeout: 10s\nrule_files:\n- /etc/config/recording_rules.yml\n- /etc/config/alerting_rules.yml\n- /etc/config/rules\n- /etc/config/alerts\nscrape_configs:\n- job_name: prometheus\n  static_configs:\n  - targets:\n    - localhost:9090\n- bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token\n  job_name: kubernetes-apiservers\n  kubernetes_sd_configs:\n  - role: endpoints\n  relabel_configs:\n  - action: keep\n    regex: default;kubernetes;https\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_namespace\n    - __meta_kubernetes_service_name\n    - __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name\n  scheme: https\n  tls_config:\n    ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt\n    insecure_skip_verify: true\n- bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token\n  job_name: kubernetes-nodes\n  kubernetes_sd_configs:\n  - role: node\n  relabel_configs:\n  - action: labelmap\n    regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)\n  - replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443\n    target_label: __address__\n  - regex: (.+)\n    replacement: /api/v1/nodes/$1/proxy/metrics\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_node_name\n    target_label: __metrics_path__\n  scheme: https\n  tls_config:\n    ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt\n    insecure_skip_verify: true\n- bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token\n  job_name: kubernetes-nodes-cadvisor\n  kubernetes_sd_configs:\n  - role: node\n  relabel_configs:\n  - action: labelmap\n    regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)\n  - replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443\n    target_label: __address__\n  - regex: (.+)\n    replacement: /api/v1/nodes/$1/proxy/metrics/cadvisor\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_node_name\n    target_label: __metrics_path__\n  scheme: https\n  tls_config:\n    ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt\n    insecure_skip_verify: true\n- honor_labels: true\n  job_name: kubernetes-service-endpoints\n  kubernetes_sd_configs:\n  - role: endpoints\n  relabel_configs:\n  - action: keep\n    regex: true\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape\n  - action: drop\n    regex: true\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape_slow\n  - action: replace\n    regex: (https?)\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme\n    target_label: __scheme__\n  - action: replace\n    regex: (.+)\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path\n    target_label: __metrics_path__\n  - action: replace\n    regex: ([^:]+)(?::\\d+)?;(\\d+)\n    replacement: $1:$2\n    source_labels:\n    - __address__\n    - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port\n    target_label: __address__\n  - action: labelmap\n    regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_param_(.+)\n    replacement: __param_$1\n  - action: labelmap\n    regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)\n  - action: replace\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_namespace\n    target_label: namespace\n  - action: replace\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_service_name\n    target_label: service\n  - action: replace\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name\n    target_label: node\n- honor_labels: true\n  job_name: kubernetes-service-endpoints-slow\n  kubernetes_sd_configs:\n  - role: endpoints\n  relabel_configs:\n  - action: keep\n    regex: true\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape_slow\n  - action: replace\n    regex: (https?)\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme\n    target_label: __scheme__\n  - action: replace\n    regex: (.+)\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path\n    target_label: __metrics_path__\n  - action: replace\n    regex: ([^:]+)(?::\\d+)?;(\\d+)\n    replacement: $1:$2\n    source_labels:\n    - __address__\n    - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port\n    target_label: __address__\n  - action: labelmap\n    regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_param_(.+)\n    replacement: __param_$1\n  - action: labelmap\n    regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)\n  - action: replace\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_namespace\n    target_label: namespace\n  - action: replace\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_service_name\n    target_label: service\n  - action: replace\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name\n    target_label: node\n  scrape_interval: 5m\n  scrape_timeout: 30s\n- honor_labels: true\n  job_name: prometheus-pushgateway\n  kubernetes_sd_configs:\n  - role: service\n  relabel_configs:\n  - action: keep\n    regex: pushgateway\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_probe\n- honor_labels: true\n  job_name: kubernetes-services\n  kubernetes_sd_configs:\n  - role: service\n  metrics_path: /probe\n  params:\n    module:\n    - http_2xx\n  relabel_configs:\n  - action: keep\n    regex: true\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_probe\n  - source_labels:\n    - __address__\n    target_label: __param_target\n  - replacement: blackbox\n    target_label: __address__\n  - source_labels:\n    - __param_target\n    target_label: instance\n  - action: labelmap\n    regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)\n  - source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_namespace\n    target_label: namespace\n  - source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_service_name\n    target_label: service\n- honor_labels: true\n  job_name: kubernetes-pods\n  kubernetes_sd_configs:\n  - role: pod\n  relabel_configs:\n  - action: keep\n    regex: true\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape\n  - action: drop\n    regex: true\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape_slow\n  - action: replace\n    regex: (https?)\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme\n    target_label: __scheme__\n  - action: replace\n    regex: (.+)\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path\n    target_label: __metrics_path__\n  - action: replace\n    regex: ([^:]+)(?::\\d+)?;(\\d+)\n    replacement: $1:$2\n    source_labels:\n    - __address__\n    - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port\n    target_label: __address__\n  - action: labelmap\n    regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_param_(.+)\n    replacement: __param_$1\n  - action: labelmap\n    regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)\n  - action: replace\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_namespace\n    target_label: namespace\n  - action: replace\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_pod_name\n    target_label: pod\n  - action: drop\n    regex: Pending|Succeeded|Failed|Completed\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_pod_phase\n- honor_labels: true\n  job_name: kubernetes-pods-slow\n  kubernetes_sd_configs:\n  - role: pod\n  relabel_configs:\n  - action: keep\n    regex: true\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape_slow\n  - action: replace\n    regex: (https?)\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme\n    target_label: __scheme__\n  - action: replace\n    regex: (.+)\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path\n    target_label: __metrics_path__\n  - action: replace\n    regex: ([^:]+)(?::\\d+)?;(\\d+)\n    replacement: $1:$2\n    source_labels:\n    - __address__\n    - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port\n    target_label: __address__\n  - action: labelmap\n    regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_param_(.+)\n    replacement: __param_$1\n  - action: labelmap\n    regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)\n  - action: replace\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_namespace\n    target_label: namespace\n  - action: replace\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_pod_name\n    target_label: pod\n  - action: drop\n    regex: Pending|Succeeded|Failed|Completed\n    source_labels:\n    - __meta_kubernetes_pod_phase\n  scrape_interval: 5m\n  scrape_timeout: 30s\n","recording_rules.yml":"{}\n","rules":"{}\n"},"kind":"ConfigMap","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"prometheus","chart":"prometheus-15.9.0","component":"server","heritage":"Helm","release":"prometheus"},"name":"prometheus","namespace":"istio-system"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2023-02-01T04:57:40Z"
  labels:
    app: prometheus
    chart: prometheus-15.9.0
    component: server
    heritage: Helm
    release: prometheus
  name: prometheus
  namespace: istio-system
  resourceVersion: "10173050"
  uid: 2df90740-9fed-4944-8d1a-89f0e7295996
```

The pod is in running state but on grafana I am able to see all namespaces.

To observe just the metric of a single namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you want monitoring only the current namespace where Prometheus pod runs, then put the following `namespaces` config option inside every `kubernetes_sd_config`:

```yaml
kubernetes_sd_configs:
- ... your config here
  namespaces:
    own_namespace: true
```

For example:

```yaml
scrape_configs:
- job_name: kubernetes-service-endpoints
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints
    namespaces:
      own_namespace: true
```

If you need monitoring only the specified namespace (for example, `foobar`), then use the following config:

```yaml
kubernetes_sd_configs:
- ... your config here
  namespaces:
    names:
    - foobar
```

See [kubernetes_sd_configs docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/sd_configs.html#kubernetes_sd_configs) for more details.

Comment: I tried the above but it did not work. Can you just update in below sample as to where exactly it should be added.
```
    - honor_labels: true
      job_name: kubernetes-service-endpoints
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints
```

Comment: Also you can see for pods I have used the same setup as you mentioned but it did not work.

Comment: Added the example